# "from sklearn import svm" doesn't work while "import sklearn" works

Tags: python, macos, machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn

Any idea why the following isn't working? I have set the version of my Python to 2.7 also. I even reinstalled the `sklearn` with `pip` in the hope it will get installed but it didn't work! Any help is really appreciated!

```
>>> from sklearn import svm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/classes.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import BaseLibLinear, BaseSVC, BaseLibSVM
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import libsvm, liblinear
  File "numpy.pxd", line 861, in init sklearn.svm.libsvm (sklearn/svm/libsvm.c:9100)
ValueError: numpy.ufunc has the wrong size, try recompiling
>>> import sklearn
>>>
```

Comment: Do you use virtual environments? Do you have other pythons and numpy versions installed? How exactly did you resinstall sklearn?

Comment: I installed it using `pip install -U scikit-learn` and I have these other Python versions `Available versions for python:
 none
 python25-apple
 python26
 python26-apple
 python27 (active)
 python27-apple`

Comment: which python are you using? what outputs `which python` and `which pip` commands?

Comment: also, what output gives `import numpy; print numpy.__file__`?

Comment: This is the output: `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc` as I said I am using version 2.7 and the output is `monas-mbp:r mona$ which python
/opt/local/bin/python
monas-mbp:r mona$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip`

Comment: The error you provide tells that sklearn is compiled against wrong numpy headers. Any chances that usr/local/bin/pip points to pip from python27-apple? So pip do not tuch sklearn you're using. And moreover, did `pip install -U sciit-learn` in reinstalled sklearn?